# How to handle KendoUI Validator validate event

Tags: kendo-ui

I'd like to disable Save button when any control becomes invalid. Kendo docs claim that there is `validate` event, but it didn't work for me:

```
$('#test1').kendoValidator({
    validate: function(e) {
        console.log(e.valid);
    }
});

var validatable = $('#test3').kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

validatable.bind('validate', function(e) {
    console.log(e.valid);
});
```

Any ideas how to handle the event?

http://jsfiddle.net/qqoppu57/

Answer (score 0):

You should add form element and submit button and `validatable.bind` is useless.
See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qqoppu57/3/)

Or calling manually validate method [Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/validator#methods-validateb)

Because when input loses focus validate method is not triggered